# Refer to different sheet and defined variable in VBA vlookup

Tags: excel, vba

This is part of the vba code (modified recorded Macro) I currently have:

```
Dim strSheet1 As String, strSheet2 As String, lngRow as Long

Sheets(strSheet1).Select

lngRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Range("J2").Select
    
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(RC[-1],'SFDB'!R2C15:R[47]C15,1,FALSE)),""No"","""")"
```

I'm trying to:

1. change the `'SFDB'!` to something like `strSheet2!`, but running this, excel would ask me to select another excel file (`strSheet1` and `strSheet2` are both from InputBox)
2. change `R[47]` to `R[lngRow]`, but this would lead to an error "Method FormulaR1C1 of Object Range Failed"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take the parameter `strSheet1` and `lngRow` outside the `"` section.

Change:

```
"=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(RC[-1],'SFDB'!R2C15:R[47]C15,1,FALSE)),""No"","""")"
```

With:

```
"=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(RC[-1],'" & strSheet1 & " '!R2C15:R[" & lngRow & "]C15,1,FALSE)),""No"","""")"
```

Also, avoid using `Select` and `ActiveCell`, instead use fully qualified `Range` and `Worksheet` objects.

Look at slightly modified code below:

```
Dim strSheet1 As String, strSheet2 As String, lngRow As Long

With Sheets(strSheet1)
    lngRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    .Range("J2").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(RC[-1],'" & strSheet1 & " '!R2C15:R[" & lngRow & "]C15,1,FALSE)),""No"","""")"
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
rows.count = rows + 1
dim wint = rows
lngRow = Cells(Rows.Count, wint).End(xlUp).Row
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it